# Automatic loading of a ROS launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to configure my Ubuntu 11.04 such that it automatically boot into console (instead of graphical interface) and then run a ROS launch file. Any idea how to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12774/automatic-loading-of-a-ros-launch-file/) by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to disable Ubuntu's GUI, you can follow these steps:

Edit "/etc/init/gdm.conf" and comment out the following lines:

```
 start on (filesystem
           and started hal
           and tty-device-added KERNEL=tty7
           and (graphics-device-added or stopped udevtrigger))
```

so that they look like this:

```
#start on (filesystem
#          and started hal
#          and tty-device-added KERNEL=tty7
#          and (graphics-device-added or stopped udevtrigger))
```

As far as autoboot of roslaunch, I've demonstrated that in my answer to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/2713/ros-autostart-with-daemontools) question. Have a look.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4